# How to use Cluster Pool in Jobs cluster in Azure Databricks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

We are using All-purpose cluster for performing stream processing in Azure databricks and the cost is rising rapidly.

We want to move the workloads to Jobs compute to reduce the costs but we also want to have a cap on number of worker nodes and want to keep warmup times under control.

We created Cluster Pools but unsure how we can use them in Jobs compute.

I saw we can edit the All-purpose cluster config to use nodes from Cluster pools but will they be charged like Jobs compute ?

If not - how can we leverage a certain jobs compute configuration in all the streaming jobs  and still keep the overall number of worked nodes limited and reuse them ?

Thanks

Comment: @alexott - your guidance would be a great help here !!

Answer (score 1):

When creating your job compute for the workflow, you have the option to choose from a pool.

[image: compute form pool]